# string and malloc...whats goes wrong?

Tags: c, string, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int i, *x , size ;
    char name[100] , *y;

    printf("Give name: ");

    /* user gives name */
    gets(name);
    size = strlen(name);


    /* gets memory for exactly the name length */
    y=(char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));

    for(i=0;i!='\0';i++) {

        /* corywrites the name */
        *(y+i)=name[i];
    }

    printf("%s" ,*y);
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0;i!='\0';i++){` <- you are comparing the iterator, you need to compare the character value -> `for(i=0;name[i]!='\0';i++){`

Comment: C strings are null terminated.  The size needs to be incremented by 1.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845). Also, `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1.

Comment: don't use `gets`. it is inherently dangerous and has been removed from the C standard

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell us what problems/symptoms you're seeing...but for starters...

- test `name[i] != '\0'` instead of `i != '\0'`
- the length `strlen(name)` returns does not include the trailing `null`.
- null-terminate `y` after the `for` loop:

So...

```
y=(char*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));

for(i=0; name[i] != '\0'; i++) {    
    /* copywrites the name */
    y[i] = name[i]; /* changed to array syntax */
 }
 y[size] = '\0';

 printf("%s", y);
```

Comment: Not that this is necessarily the best way to do all this, but it's in the 'theme' of the question.

Comment: crash..! user scans the name and then the programm crashes

Comment: a) Never cast malloc in C. b) Use strcpy rather than rolling your own. (The whole thing could be replaced with strdup on POSIX systems.)

Answer (score 0):

If I would copy a string by hand it would look like:

```
int i;
for( i = 0; source[i]; i++ ) dest[i] = source[i]; // copy characters
dest[i] = 0; // append null terminator
```

When you allocate the string you need to add 1 for the null terminator, and after you copy the string, you also need to add the null terminator.

You have a problem where you are comparing `i` to `'\0'` which is the initial condition and it terminates immediately.

An easier way to copy a string is to use the strcpy function.

Comment: `for( i = 0; (dest[i] = source[i]); i++ ) ;` avoids the need for a separate `dest[i] = 0;` ... but seriously, just use strcpy.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't allocate enough memory for `y`. You need to allocate space for the number of characters in the string plus one more for the null terminating character.

   ```
   y = malloc(size + 1);
   ```
2. Your loop condition is broken. You probably are looking to compare the ith value in the string:

   ```
   for (i=0; name[i]!='\0'; i++) {
   ```
3. Instead of writing `*(y+i)`, you should just write `y[i]`. It's more understandable and it has exactly the same semantics.

   ```
   for (i=0; name[i]!='\0'; i++) {
       y[i] = name[i];
   }
   ```
4. You didn't null terminate `y`.

   ```
   y[size] = '\0';
   ```
5. When printing a string, the argument is expected to be of type `char *`, not `char`. So:

   ```
   printf("%s", y);
   ```